# How to properly Name an association table (One to one relationship)

Tags: sql, database, associations, one-to-one

Most of the time I come across many to many (**Cross Reference**) table, name like **Table1Table2XRef**.

But what is the best way to name a one to one association table?

I know I can migrate foreign keys in one or another table, but I am more concerned about the proper way of naming them with regards of good practices.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best name to give a one-to-one association table is exactly the same as the best name to give any table: whatever is the most meaningful to you and your group.

If you feel that a 1-1 cross reference table needs to have a different name than a n-m cross reference table, then take a vote. Maybe **Table1Table2YRef** will win (many in today's society consider a Y to be half an X).

Whatever floats your boat. Just agree on something sensible, apply it consistently and get back to work.

Btw, how many of these tables do you have. In 20+ years, I don't remember ever coming across one. There are easier ways to establish a 1-1 relationship. About the only reason I can think of where one would be useful is if the relationships break up and reform on a regular basis (kinda like a lot of marriages).

**Addendum**: a typical 1-1 implementation. When breaking up a large table with many fields that are rarely used, normalizing those fields to a separate table.

MainTable:

```
PK: 1001, F1, F2, ..., F75
PK: 1002, F1, F2, ..., F75
PK: 1003, F1, F2, ..., F75
```

Result:
MainTable:

```
PK: 1001, F1, F2, ..., F15
PK: 1002, F1, F2, ..., F15
PK: 1003, F1, F2, ..., F15
```

SubTable:

```
PK: 1001, F16, F17, ..., F15
PK: 1002, F16, F17, ..., F15
PK: 1003, F16, F17, ..., F15

create table SubTable(
    ID   int not null,
    ..., -- F16 thru f75
    constraint PK_SubTable primary key( ID ),
    constraint FK_SubTable_MainTable foreign key( ID )
         references Maintable( ID );
);
```

Comment: that's a n excellent answer. I came to this because I wanted to improve the performance of retriving data on a very large table, I decided to split here and keep apart the columns that are mostly used with the `SELECT`

Comment: You may want to look into covering indexes to, in effect, create a sub-table within a larger table. That helps with large tables. If you still decide to split them up, in the second table, store the same ID value of the main table as that table's ID and define it as both the PK and FK to the main table. This establishes and enforces the 1-1 relationship without a separate table. To use the formatting capabilities, I'll tack on an example in the answer.

Comment: cheers, your help is valuable. I guess you refer abstract and specialized table. I get it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As seen here:

[link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

the one to one relationships on database, can be Unidirectional, Bidirectional, or just have a self-reference.

**Unidirectional:**

Only one key migrates to another table

**Bidirectional:**

Both primary keys become migrate as foreign keys.

**self-Reference:**

There is a foreign key referencing its own primary key.